# Exporting Subversion log to CSV

Tags: svn, logging

Is there a simple way to export the subversion logs to a CSV file?

I want to use them to approximate my hours spent on a project and doing so in an spreadsheet would be easy.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This short Python script will provide a CSV with your SVN log output:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

log_text = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'log', '--xml'] + sys.argv[1:],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
log_xml = etree.XML(log_text)

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for child in log_xml.getchildren():
        csv_writer.writerow([
                child.attrib['revision'],
                child.findtext('date'), 
                child.findtext('author').encode('utf-8'),
                child.findtext('msg').encode('utf-8'),
        ])
```

It passes through command-line arguments to the underlying SVN call, so if you only want to see revision 34 and later, you can invoke it as follows:

```
$ svnlog2csv -r 34:HEAD >my_spreadsheet.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanx for the script !  I added this slight modification because our SVN repository is UTF-8 with accented characters (French) and the script borked :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
import codecs

log_text = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'log', '--xml'] + sys.argv[1:],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
log_xml = etree.XML(log_text)

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for child in log_xml.getchildren():
        csv_writer.writerow([
                child.attrib['revision'],
                child.findtext('date'),
                child.findtext('author'),
                child.findtext('msg').encode("utf-8"),
        ])
```

Cheers,

Comment: FYI - you don't need to import `codecs` to call `encode` on a string; that said, this is a useful addition, and I hope you'll forgive me for adopting it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all, very helpful. I found that on Windows computers the python csv_writer expects binary file output, otherwise extra carriage returns get emitted. The following script handles this case, and also removes newlines in the middle of commit messages (replaced with front-slash) to ensure one-line output.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

log_text = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'log', '--xml'] + sys.argv[1:],
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
log_xml = etree.XML(log_text)

if sys.platform == "win32":
    import os, msvcrt
    msvcrt.setmode(sys.stdout.fileno(), os.O_BINARY)

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

for child in log_xml.getchildren():
        csv_writer.writerow([
                child.attrib['revision'],
                child.findtext('date'),
                child.findtext('author'),
                child.findtext('msg').encode("utf-8").replace('\n','/'),
        ])
```

(Now, who else wishes svn log took the same options as git log?? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Another quick solution which I have had great success with is [here at Chris' blog](http://gotochriswest.com/blog/2012/10/02/svn-log-to-csv-converter/).  It is a Java program which quickly converts it to a CSV file.  You can also use the online version that is shown there.  Usually he posts JavaScript articles, but I guess he knows Java too since they are supposedly pretty similar.

Comment: Java != JavaScript they aren't 'similar' in anyway other than they have `Java` in the name; which someone at Netscape should be beaten for doing.

Answer (score 1):

[@Charles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14122/charles-duffy), here's a Python 3 implementation that adds a header row at the beginning and adjusts the commit date to local time.
[@Yves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/538089/yves-moisan), I did not keep your `.encode("utf-8")` addition because in Python 3 all strings are Unicode, so re-encoding should not be necessary. I did some very limited testing and found that extended characters, such as vowels with diacritical marks, were preserved. There is no sanitizing of EOL characters in the commit messages. If there are newlines and/or carriage returns in the commit messages, Excel will not import the data correctly. Numbers, however, does.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import subprocess
import sys
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree
from datetime import datetime

log_text = subprocess.Popen(['svn', 'log', '--xml'] + sys.argv[1:], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
log_xml = etree.XML(log_text)

csv_writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

csv_writer.writerow(['revision', 'date', 'author', 'commit message'])

for child in log_xml.iter('logentry'):
    csv_writer.writerow([
        child.attrib['revision'],
        datetime.strptime(child.findtext('date').replace('Z', ' +0000'), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f %z').astimezone().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
        child.findtext('author'),
        child.findtext('msg')
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this handy little script

```
svn log -r {2015-05-01}:{2015-05-31} http://svn.company.co.id/dev/ |  tr -d '\n' | sed -r 's/-{2,}/\n/g' | sed -r 's/ \([^\)]+\)//g' | sed -r 's/^r//' | sed -r "s/[0-9]+ lines?//g" | sort -g | sed 's/ | /;/g' > list.csv
```

which exports svn log from dates 1st May 2015 to 31st May 2015 list.csv.. here i'm using semi colon as separators.. because my developers use commas in their notes..